# Case-sensitive file names in Windows' Linux subsystem

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, filenames

I'm running Windows 10 and I frequently use the Linux subsystem on Windows.

If I use the Linux system to create a folder, the file names in that folder will be case sensitive. This will sometimes confuse Windows programs that access the folder.

Is there a simple way to modify a Linux folder so that its file names are no longer case sensitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Microsoft's initial post about [per-directory case sensitivity](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/02/28/per-directory-case-sensitivity-and-wsl/) (added in Windows 10.1803), you can change the mode using `fsutil.exe` from the Windows side:

```
fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo <path> disable
```